# fstream getline() Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getline

am trying to read a file so am doing:-

```
void Load(const char * Name){
    fs.open(Name, std::ifstream::in);
        char temp[256];

    if(fs.is_open()){

        while (!fs.eof())
        {
            fs.getline(temp , 256);
            Lines.push_back(new std::string(temp));
        }
}
}
```

but it breaks on the `getline` ->

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7730B4D9 (ntdll.dll) in GameCore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

where it's check

```
else
            /*
             * Not part of _iob[]. Therefore, *pf is a _FILEX and the
             * lock field of the struct is an initialized critical
             * section.
             */
            EnterCriticalSection( &(((_FILEX *)pf)->lock) );
```

in the `_file.c` file , what's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like memory corruption, but I can't see anything in that code that would cause it. Probably it happened just before you called this function. I can see several things wrong with your code however.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter these sorts of issues you may want to double check your project configuration. For example, in MSVC check your Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library. Make sure it consistent for all dependencies and that it is set to a Debug/Release variant depending on the current build.