# unhandled exception at xxxxx unable to write at location. It doesn't execute beyond the getline....... in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

```
  #include "StdAfx.h"


   int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {
  // using namespace std;
  string line;
  cout<<"dsadasdas";
  fstream file  ("D:\source_details.txt", ios::in);
  cout<<"dsadasdas"<<endl;

  if (file.is_open())
   {    cout<<"dsadasdas";
        getline (file,line);
     cout<<"dsadasdas";
    cout<<line;
    }
  else
   {
    cout<<"Not possible"<<endl;

   }




    return (0);
   }
```

the code doesnt get executed beyond the getline...... I get the unhandled exception error. I dont understand what is wrong with my code. It is really simple. Actually this is a very small part of a big code i am trying to run in visual studio but i keep getting this error.

Comment: Did you try to debug into the library calls?

Comment: Your code is working good for me after i put `"D:\\source_details.txt"` instead of `"D:\source_details.txt"`. But even with `"D:\source_details.txt"`, i'm not getting any exception, just that the file is not getting opened, that's all!

Answer (score 3):

```
fstream file  ("D:\source_details.txt", ios::in);
```

You need to escape '\' symbol here, like this:

```
fstream file  ("D:\\source_details.txt", ios::in);
```

Comment: Hmm, then try looking at your project configuration, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14099909/1641779).